# How to set different Toggle start position in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple jQuery toggle button but I don't want to use toggleSlide. If it is loaded homepage, the div must be opened and have a button to hide.
But if it is loaded another page, div must be closed and have button to show
Here is two code, that doesn't work. I try to add them together in HTML but doesn't work

For homepage:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    if(window.location.href == 'http://homepage/')
      $("#panel").hide("fast");
  }); 
});
```

for another page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    if(window.location.href != 'http://homepage/')
      $("#panel").show("fast");
  }); 
});
```

Comment: How about you just add a class to the element on the homepage and check for that in your click handler? `$("#flip").click(function(){ if(!$(this).hasClass("noToggle")){ $("#panel").slideToggle("fast"); }; }); });`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var condition = (window.location.href == 'http://homepage/');
   $("#panel").toggle(condition);
});
```

But comparing strings is usually bad practice, so what I would do is set a bool at the top of the page, and when the homepage is loaded, set it to true. Otherwise, false.

Comment: i wrote something that doesnot work. please can u look at it?

Comment: How can be wrotten zour suggestion with hideä

Comment: What did you write that didn't work? Please update your question with the code that didn't work and I will be able to help you better.

Comment: Okay I updated my answer, please let me know if this works. This should work universally, no need to write it twice. Also try doing a Console.Log on window.location.href and see exactly what it returns.

Comment: What means condition in .toggle(condition)? must i write anything else?

Comment: It's just a boolean I've already defined one line above. It just looks cleaner than putting the condition directly in the function.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
       console.log(window.location.href);
     });

Comment: Try that, look at the console log whenever the page loads and make absolutely SURE that `http://homepage/` is the URL you are loading. I'm pretty sure it should be something like `http://localhost/homepage/` but you never know.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple elements with the ID of "panel", then it won't work. ID's should be unique for every element.